# GAE: auto running tests for “Run As Web Application” or “Deploy to App Engine”

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, junit

I am developing a simple GAE project with Eclipse and just added my first unit test (using JUnit). How can I let my tests run automatically when starting the web application locally or before deploying it to the GAE server?

Is maven mandatory here or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not exactly what I was looking for, but probably good enough:

https://infinitest.github.io/

This plugin runs the tests each time code was modified.